# Can we Share a Newsfeed inside the MySite with specific user/s only, inside sharepoint enterprise 2013 on-premises

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, mysite, newsfeed

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 on-premises. and i have enabled the MySites creation for our users. but seems a user can add a Newsfeed inside his MySite, and can ONLY share it with either the following 2 options:-

1. Everyone
2. Sites which the user is following.

as follow:-

[image]

**but seems there is not an option to share the news-feed with specif user/s or specific group of users**? i am not sure if there is a way to do this or this is not provide?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Target Audience setting on the Newsfeed webpart to display it only to a group of users.

1. Create a SharePoint group (Site Settings, People and Groups, Click "Groups" on the left quick launch menu, and then click New, New Group)
2. Add the users you want to see the newsfeed webpart to the newly
   created group
3. Go to the page with the newsfeed webpart, edit the page, and click
   "Edit web part" in the top right corner of the newsfeed area (it is
   in a dropdown hidden menu)
4. Add the newly created group into the "Target Audiences" section of
   the webpart properties (you will find it in the "Advanced" section.
   See below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. You can use only options as you wrote. To reading/writing NewsFeed uses the Distributed Cache. It's difficult to modify its mechanism.

In my project we created custom page to reading/writing NewsFeed, and we filtered messages according to the text (we used text labels containing the necessary business information in a text message). But this is a very time consuming and not safety solution.

Please consider using Yammer or Teams.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to accomplish this requirement of which I am aware.

Newsfeeds limited to specific groups of people are provided with Team sites, which makes sense since it is team based.

You can use the mention feature to provide a user with a notification email (E.g. @John G: message to John!), but it won't prevent other users from viewing the message if profiles are public.